Bounding Expectations in a Renewal-Like Process
I am studying a discrete-time process $M_t$ defined as follows:

$M_0 = 1$,
$M_t = M_{t-1} + X_t$ if $M_{t-1} > 0$,
$M_t = 1$ otherwise,

where $(X_t)_{t=1}^\infty$ are i.i.d. random variables satisfying $E[X_t] = -\mu$ for some $\mu > 0$, and $|X_t| \leq 1$ almost surely.
I am interested in bounding the following quantities:

$E[M_t]$ for a fixed $t$,
$E\left[\max_{1 \leq t \leq n} M_t\right]$ for a fixed $n$.

My Approach
1. Bounding $E[M_t]$:
Using a tail-sum formula and monotonicity, $E[M_t] \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(M_t \geq n).$ Next, focus on $n \geq 2$. Observe that if $M_t>n$, then we have a sequence $S_T = \sum_{i=1}^T X_i$ such that $S_T \geq n$ for $T>n$. Thus,
$$\Pr(M_t \geq n) \leq \Pr(S_T \geq n) \leq \Pr(S_T \geq 0) = \Pr(S_T +T\mu \geq T\mu)\leq \Pr(S_T +T\mu \geq n\mu) .$$
using Hoeffding inequality on the above, we get $\Pr(M_t \geq n) \leq \exp (\frac{-T\mu^2}{2}) \leq  \exp (\frac{-n\mu^2}{2})$. [I suspect the above step is the reason this bound might be loose].
Finally,
$$ 
E[M_t] \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(M_t \geq n)\leq 2 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \exp (\frac{-n\mu^2}{2}) \leq 2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp (\frac{-n\mu^2}{2})\leq 2 + \frac{\exp (\frac{-\mu^2}{2})}{1-\exp (\frac{-\mu^2}{2})}\leq 2+\frac{2}{\mu^2},
$$
where the last step is due to Bernoulli inequality.
2. Bounding $E\left[\max_{1 \leq t \leq n} M_t\right]$:
Using a similar approach, I can get a high probability bound for some constant $C$:
$$
\Pr{\left( \max_{1\leq t\leq n} M_t> \frac{C}{\mu}\ln n \right)}\leq \frac{2}{n}.
$$
This suggests $E\left[\max_{1 \leq t \leq n} M_t\right] \leq \frac {C\ln n}{\mu}$.
Questions

How can I obtain a tighter bound for $E[M_t]$? Is it possible to achieve $E[M_t] \leq \frac{1}{\mu}$?
As for $E\left[\max_{1 \leq t \leq n} M_t\right]$, can the $\ln n $ factor be improved? intuitively, yes, as I expect the bound on the expected value to be smaller than the high probability bound.

Any insights or references to similar problems in renewal processes or drift analysis would be appreciated. Thank you!
